# Why is my lawn sprinkler backflow preventer failing?

Tags: backflow-preventer

I have 14 zones which work fine except for zone 6. When it starts water starts coming out of backflow preventer. I already changed the valve parts and solenoid. Is there any thing else I can check?

Comment: Traditional sprinkler designs have one back flo preventer regardless of number of stations. Sounds like a problem with the station valve.

Comment: You could improve your question by providing more details on the sprinkler and a photo

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a blockage in that zone and the water is dispersed through the backflow.

Try taking the heads off at the beginning of the zone.  Also look for damp ground where a brake may have occurred.   If you had a break and repaired it there may be debris in the pipe that has been compressed by the water and is now a solid block.